# Parsing Java command line arguments when jar file and main class are specified

Tags: java, command, arguments, command-line-arguments

My java execution is run as follows:

```
java -cp jar mainClass argA argB argC
```

What does `argA` correspond to? `args[1]` or `args[4]` ? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Answer (score 2):

If your main method is defined as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Then `argA` will be in `args[0]`.

See [Oracle's Command-Line Arguments tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for an example program.